# Double getting converted to Int WPF C#

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, int, label, double

I am working on a WPF Application using C#. My situation is such that I need the absoluted value of a double and then display it in the a label, for ex, if I have

`double d=-17.00;`

`myLbl.Content=Math.Abs(d);` 
OR

`myLbl.Content=Math.Abs(d).ToString();`

This should simply set my label to **17.00**, but no! It instead sets my label to **17**. I need to keep the precision upto 2 decimal places, in all cases.

What can I do? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string value = Math.Abs(-17.00).ToString("0.00");

//value: "17.00"
```

Comment: Thanks. While trying @kenneth 's answer I tried this and it worked. Marking this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the output string:

```
myLbl.Content=Math.Abs(d).ToString("0.##%");
```